# IndexError: list index out of range на втором цикле

Tags: python, selenium

Помогите кто не будь в чем проблема. Пишу небольшого бота лайкера постов ВК, наткнулся на непонятную ошибку. Первый цикл проходит без нареканий на втором цикле выдает

> window_after = driver.window_handles[1]   IndexError: list index out of range

если кликать вручную все работает CLASS у всех кнопок одинаковый. Почему он не может найти класс?

```py
for item in driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "insidebtn"):
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", item)
        
    time.sleep(2)
    window_after = driver.window_handles[1]
    driver.switch_to.window(window_after)

    time.sleep(2)

    url = driver.current_url
    result = re.search(r"/([a-z]+)(-?\d+)_(\d+)", url)

    type_name, owner_id, item_id = result.groups()
    if type_name == "wall":
        type_name = "post"
    url = 'https://api.vk.com/method/likes.add?type=%s&owner_id=%s&item_id=%s&v=5.131&access_token=%s' % (type_name, owner_id, item_id, token)
    req = requests.get(url).text

    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])
    time.sleep(3)
    driver.close()
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])
    time.sleep(5)
```

Решил пойти другим путем, распарсить кнопку не переходя по ссылке вытянуть параметры отправить запрос на vk api и кликнуть на проверку.
Может кто подскажет как из

```html
<div class="insidebtn" id="load4468979" onclick="proverka(4468979, 4468979, &quot;vklike&quot;, &quot;https://vk.com/photo174636499_457239378&quot;);">
  <i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i>&nbsp;8 баллов
</div>
```

вытащить https://vk.com/photo174636499_457239378

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    for url1 in users_url:
        print(url1)
        time.sleep(2)
        #url1 = driver.current_url ### Забрать ссылку из адресной строки
        result = re.search(r"/([a-z]+)(-?\d+)_(\d+)", url1)
        type_name, owner_id, item_id = result.groups()
        if type_name == "wall":
            type_name = "post"
        url = 'https://api.vk.com/method/likes.add?type=%s&owner_id=%s&item_id=%s&v=5.131&access_token=%s' % (type_name, owner_id, item_id, token)
        req = requests.post(url).json()
        print(req)
        try:
            if req != req['response']['likes']:
                continue
        except:

            error = req['error']['error_code']
            if error == 14:
                #print("error")
                captcha_sid = req['error']['captcha_sid']
                captcha_img = req['error']['captcha_img']

                with open('newfile.jpg', 'wb') as target:
                    a = requests.post(f'{captcha_img}')
                    target.write(a.content)
                captcha_key = vc.solve(image='newfile.jpg')
                print(f"Капча : {captcha_key}")
                url = 'https://api.vk.com/method/likes.add?captcha_sid=%s&captcha_key=%s&type=%s&owner_id=%s&item_id=%s&v=5.131&access_token=%s' % (
                captcha_sid, captcha_key, type_name, owner_id, item_id, token)
                req = requests.post(url).json()

            print(req)
```